# Weird GCC array initialization behavior

Tags: c++, gcc

I encountered a variant of this code when looking at another question (the original code used a `std::thread` instead of `std::vector`, but the syntax is the same):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> vecs[10] = std::vector<double>(10, 1);
    for(auto& vec: vecs){
        std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code shouldn't compile; `std::vector<double> vecs[10] = std::vector<double>(10, 1);` is not valid initialization syntax, and clang rejects it with `error: array initializer must be an initializer list`. However, GCC [accepts it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73fc5f26c3e187e0) and appears to initialize every vector in the list with a copy of the specified temporary.

Is this some GCC extension I've never heard about (that somehow also managed to survive `-pedantic-errors`) or just a plain bug?

Comment: I'm guessing difference in language standard?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Both are in C++11 mode, and AFAIK that syntax has never been legal in C++.

Comment: Is this not the **(2) fill constructor**, as mentioned [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/)? *Edit*: Ah nevermind, missed the array in your variable declaration.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Yes, that's a valid constructor, the problem is the attempt to use that to initialize the array. That should not compile.

Comment: Looks like a plain bug to me. I removed the C++11 stuff from your example code and gcc happily accepts it in C++98 mode as well.

Comment: Minimal example: `struct a {a();} x[2] = a();`. gcc compiles it. Without the constructor declaration, it won't. Clearly a bug.

Comment: @n.m. Would you submit a bug report? I am happy to submit a bug report as well if you are busy or don't want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would consider this a bug.

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<double> x = std::vector<double>(10, 1);
  std::vector<double> vecs[10] = x;
  return 0;
}
```

Works (as you have spotted).

While

```
int main()
{
  int x = 10;
  int is[10] = x;
  return 0;
}
```

yields the (expected) error.

Answer (score 2):

Further investigation:

```
struct A { A() { } };
int main() { A a[10] = A(); }
```

This compiles in GCC.

```
struct A { A() = default; };
int main() { A a[10] = A(); }
```

Also compiles in GCC 4.9 but not earlier versions I tested (4.6-4.8).

```
struct A { };
int main() { A a[10] = A(); }
```

Doesn't compile.

```
struct B { virtual ~B() { } };
struct A : B { };
int main() { A a[10] = A(); }
```

Compiles.

```
struct B {  ~B() { } };
struct A : B { };
int main() { A a[10] = A(); }
```

Doesn't compile.

I think it's safe to say that it's a bug. No sane extension would have this sort of behavior. Note that `A` in both the second case and the third case are POD types (the only difference being an explicitly defaulted default constructor), but they are treated differently by GCC 4.9.

Edit: Going through the GCC bugzilla again, [this bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60009) appears to be related. Looks like I missed it the first time through because the title was talking about string literals.