# Array initializer must be an initializer list error not shown

Tags: c++

I am having a hard time trying to figure out why this code seems to work. Shouldn't I get an "array initializer must be an initializer list" error?

```
#include <iostream>

class B {
public:
  B() { std::cout << "B Constructor " << std::endl ; }
  B(const B&) { std::cout << "B Copy Constructor " << std::endl ; }
  ~B() { std::cout << "B Destructor " << std::endl ; }
} ;

class A {
public:
  A() { std::cout << "A Constructor " << std::endl ; }
  A(const A& other) : bs(other.bs)
        { std::cout << "A Copy Constructor " << std::endl ;}
  ~A() { std::cout << "A Destructor " << std::endl ; }
private:
  B bs[12] ;
};


int main() {
    A a ;
    A b(a) ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

The output of `g++ --version` is `g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)`

Comment: Add a standard flag (`--std=c++0x` or `--std=c++03`), as well as the `-pedantic-errors` flag, and you'll see it's an extension. If that doesn't help, then GCC 4.4.7 has a bug.

Comment: Very interesting.  All version off gcc on [godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/) compile this code while all versions off clang reject it.  I suspect this is a gcc  bug/extension.  Unfortunately using `-pedantic` doesn't change anything with gcc in this case.

Comment: Possible dupe with maybe the related bug report in the second answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24378882/weird-gcc-array-initialization-behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is ill-formed, and GCC has a bug. You specify GCC 4.4.7, so I'm going to base this answer on C++11. The meaning of an initializer is determined by [[dcl.init]/16](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init#16):

> The semantics of initializers are as follows. The destination type is
>   the type of the object or reference being initialized and the source
>   type is the type of the initializer expression. If the initializer is
>   not a single (possibly parenthesized) expression, the source type is
>   not defined.
>
> - the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) braced-init-list, the object or reference is list-initialized ([dcl.init.list]).
> - If the destination type is a reference type, see [dcl.init.ref].
> - If the destination type is an array of characters, an array of char16_t, an array of char32_t, or an array of wchar_t, and the
>     initializer is a string literal, see [dcl.init.string].
> - If the initializer is `()`, the object is value-initialized.
> - **Otherwise, if the destination type is an array, the program is ill-formed.**
> - [... Continued but irrelevant here ... ]

The bullets must be checked in order to determine the meaning of an initializer for a target type. Since you use `(other.bs)` as an initializer, and the target type is an array, the only applicable bullet is the one I highlighted. The program is ill-formed.